# WTForms not validating NumberRange

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm making a WTForm which takes Decimals as inputs, and I'm trying to restrict input to a range of numbers (between 0 and 10 inclusive). However, the validator `NumberRange` doesn't seem to do anything.

Python (using flask):

```
from flask import render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DecimalField, SubmitField, validators

class NumberForm(FlaskForm):
    question = DecimalField('Question 1',
                            [validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=10, message="blah"),
                             validators.Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('some_route/', methods=['GET', 'POST])
def page():
    form = NumberForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return some_success_or_other
    return render_template('page.html', form=form)
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="form-group-row">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.question.label }}
    <div>
      {{ form.question }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-row">
    {{ form.submit }}
  </div>
</form>
```

The `question` field will be submitted whatever value I input. I thought it wouldn't allow text, nor would it allow negative numbers, nor numbers outside the range (e.g. 10000).

I've tried changing the `NumberRange` min and max to `0.0` and `10.0`. I've tried taking out the message arguments. I've tried taking out the `Optional` validator. But none of these prevents me entering out of range numbers in the form.

(When I replaced `Optional` with `DataRequired`, the form would not submit unless there was data in the field, so that validator worked at least.)

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

---

Edit: it seems the problem was split into two parts: no validation, and validation messages not flashing. The answer below fixes the lack of validation.

Comment: What does `some_success_or_other` this look like? It's been a while since I worked with WTForms but you don't seem to have anywhere to display the output from error messages. I think it might use flash() but i'm not sure I'll have a look.

Comment: @TimThompson When the `DataRequired` validator is used, an error message is flashed on the page, regardless of what `some_success_or_other` looks like.

Comment: are you providing a place in your template for that error message to be flashed?

Comment: @TimThompson. No. Good point. When I add a place for the errors they show up. But this is still different behaviour from the `DataRequired` validator which doesn't allow the form to be submitted, and flashes up the error without me modifying the HTML which is shown in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently your application is not correctly configured. The code should look like this:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, DecimalField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange

class NumberForm(FlaskForm):
    question = DecimalField('Question 1', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=10, message='bla')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Comment: how to make it validate correct decimal for example (2,2) check if integer is max 2.11 and not accept 2.111 or 333.11