# Message not flashing on some WTForm validation methods

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048287/wtforms-not-validating-numberrange/), but focussing on one of the underlying issues I didn't know about when asking that other question.

I'm using Python, Flask and WTForms to make a form. Here's the python:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DecimalField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange, DataRequired

class NumberForm(FlaskForm):
    question_one = DecimalField('Question 1', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=10)])
    question_two = DecimalField('Question 2', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('some_route/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
    form = NumberForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return some_success_or_other
    return render_template('page.html', form=form)
```

And the HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="form-group-row">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.question_one.label }}
    <div>
      {{ form.question_one }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-row">
    {{ form.question_two.label }}
    <div>
      {{ form.question_two }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-row">
    {{ form.submit }}
  </div>
</form>
```

The two validators I'm using (`NumberRange` and `DataRequired`) behave differently. When data isn't entered in field 2 and the submit button is clicked, the form isn't submitted and an error message pops up next to the field saying "Please fill in this field".

When strings (rather than decimals), or numbers outside the range is submitted in field 1, the form does submit when the button is pressed.
Although the error is logged (and can be shown using `{{ form.errors }}`, I wanted the same behaviour for both validators - I'd like the form to be prevented from submitting when invalid numbers/strings are entered in field 1.

Anyone know why the validators behave differently?

Comment: As I see `page()` processes 2 methods. Where is processing `POST`? `if flask.request.method == 'POST': ...`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I think that's handled by the `validate_on_submit` method on the `FlaskForm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 introduces the **required** attribute which makes it mandatory to fill a field and block form validation if one of the fields (affected by this attribute) has not been populated; this attribute is only available for the input tag.

With flask-wtf, when you use a field with the **required** validator, it will automatically generate a html field with the required attribute, which will block the form from being sent and display an infobule.

In the case of other validators such as `NumberRange`, it is not the same.

**With pure HTML:**

to have the same behavior, ie to check that the number entered is in a well-defined range and to block the sending of the form if it is not the case, it is necessary to use the **pattern** attribute (more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)). There is no predefined pattern for this particular case, so you will need to create a custom pattern using **regular expressions**. It will give this: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]">`.

Now we just have to reattake the same logic with wtforms...

**With wtforms:**

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group-row">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.question_one.label }}
        <div>
            {{ form.question_one(pattern="[0-9]") }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-row">
        {{ form.question_two.label }}
        <div>
            {{ form.question_two }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-row">
        {{ form.submit }}
    </div>
</form>
```

At line `{{ form.question_one(pattern="[0-9]") }}`, I use the pattern attribute with a regular expression that checks that the number entered is in the range 0 to 9. For larger ranges, you will need to write regular expressions a little more complex ([this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) is interresting)